# How to jump to active debug line in Microsoft Visual Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a program that is freezing when I run the debug. I would like to find out where. Ideally, I would do this by hitting pause during a debug run and then zoom to the active current active line. However, while I am able to run the debugger and to pause it, I can't figure out how to jump to the active line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Debug Menu under 'Call Stack' you can click on the current active line. 
[image]